# Is byte 0xFF valid in a UTF-8 encoded string?

Tags: utf-8

Can an UTF-8 string contain the byte 0xFF (255)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked Wikipedia before.  
The answer is [no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages_2).

Comment: So true, now go ahead and mark an answer ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_sequences_and_error_handling). It is specifically forbidden by the spec.

Comment: +1 The wiki article also lists the allowed character ranges under 'Description'. In no case is the binary sequence '11111111' allowed.

Comment: I'm not see it. It forbids U+00FF, which is different from  0xFF (a value used in the BOM U+FEFF)

Comment: U+00FF is ÿ and is encoded as \xC3\xBF in UTF-8. The highest byte value you can possibly have in a UTF-8 stream is 0xF4, and that's if you go into supplementary private use areas.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8, Number of 1 bytes,First code point is U+0000, Last code point is U+007F.
The bytes 0xFE and 0xFF do not valid in UTF-8.
The first byte is 0 in The UTF-8 when bytes only one.
[click image for more info about UTF-8 bytes]