# Kafka: Jhipster/SpringBoot Producer Python Consumer JSON

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, apache-kafka, jhipster

I'm trying to send a JSON through Kafka (Jhipster/SpringBoot Producer & Python Consumer), i've been able to receive the message in bytes, but when I try to decode it, i always get some problems before being able to extract the message.

My Producer is like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ProducerResource{

    private MessageChannel channel;

    public ProducerResource(ProducerChannel channel) {
        this.channel = channel.messageChannel();
    }

    @GetMapping("/subscribableChannel/{count}")
    @Timed
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public void produce(@PathVariable int count) {
        Map<String,String> json = new HashMap<String,String>();
        json.put("message","HELL YEAH");
        while(count > 0) {
            channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(json.toString().getBytes()).build());
            count--;
        }
    }

}
```

And my Python Consumer:

```
def stop_handler(signal, frame, consumer):
    print('Arrêt...')
    consumer.close()
    sys.exit(0)

def read_messages(consumer):
    meta = consumer.partitions_for_topic(TOPIC)
    for msg in consumer:
        print(msg.value)
        lol = json.load(msg.value.decode("utf-8"))
        print(lol)

def main():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(TOPIC, auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                                group_id='read', bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda signal, frame: stop_handler(signal, frame, consumer))
    read_messages(consumer)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit(main())
```

And the warning that i get from Python is:

```
python3 scripts/simple_consumer.py
b'\xff\x01\x0bcontentType\x00\x00\x00\x0c"text/plain"{message=HELL YEAH}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/simple_consumer.py", line 36, in <module>
    exit(main())
  File "scripts/simple_consumer.py", line 31, in main
    read_messages(consumer)
  File "scripts/simple_consumer.py", line 23, in read_messages
    lol = json.load(msg.value.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

In my cloud configuration i only have Consumer/Producer `HeaderMode = raw` with kafka. Any suggestion would be really appreciated!!

UPDATE---
Here is my configuration for cloud:

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
        include: swagger
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    jackson:
        serialization.indent_output: true
    cloud:
        stream:
            default:
                consumer:
                    headerMode: raw
                producer:
                    headerMode: raw
            kafka:
                binder:
                    brokers: localhost
                    zk-nodes: localhost
                bindings:
                    messageChannel:
                        destination: messageChannel
                        content-type: application/json
                    subscribableChannel:
                        destination: subscribableChannel
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657467/is-byte-0xff-valid-in-a-utf-8-encoded-string

Comment: Off the wall question because I can't see your consumer setup on the Java side... but are you using Schema Registry in your producer and not setting that up for your consumer????

Comment: i'm gonna update my question with the setting for consumer,
The Java Consumer works well, I already tested it, however with the Python Consumer i get problems