# Checking if an 8 bit character is alphanumeric

Tags: c#, ascii

This C# code would return an unexpected result:

```cs
char x = Convert.ToChar(0xff);
Console.WriteLine( Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x));
```

It prints `True` were I was hoping for a `False`. I assume this is because `IsLetterOrDigit` is expecting a Unicode character as input versus the extended ascii value I convert from.

How could I make this work? I am reading a continuous binary string from a serial port where problematic characters needs to be removed for reporting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657467/is-byte-0xff-valid-in-a-utf-8-encoded-string

Comment: As a side note, you could throw a lookup table at this, create an array of 255 booleans and use the value you put into toChar right now as the index. i don't know how much performance is a factor here, if you're processing huge gobs of data it might shave off some processing time in the long run.

Comment: 0xff is the unicode code-point `ÿ`, which absolutely is a letter, according the the unicode specification; so: why are you expecting it *not* to be? what code-point were you expecting? note that "extended ascii" is ambiguous; you need to talk about a specific code-page or encoding for that to make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Char` always [represents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) a Unicode UTF-16 character.

You need to specify *which 8 bit code page* you use. For example, the OEM US [437 Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) has a non-letter/digit character at code point #255:

```cs
int codePage = 437;

var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage);
char x = encoding.GetChars(new byte[] { 0xFF })[0];
Console.WriteLine(Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)); // False
```

Comment: [Code page 437 (CCSID 437) is the character set of the original IBM PC (personal computer).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) This is exactly I was referring to - The original IBM PC.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
char x = ascii.GetString( new Byte[] { 0xff })[0];
Console.WriteLine(Char.IsLetterOrDigit(x));
```

With [Rune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=net-5.0) manipulation

```
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
var x = ascii.GetString(new Byte[] { 0xff });
foreach(var r in x.EnumerateRunes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(Rune.IsLetterOrDigit(r));
}
```